# BootStrap Grids | Label Text Getting Wrapped and taking more space

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have tried using Grids of bootstrap first time and i found label text formats are not aligned in well manner. Label is getting wrapped up and is taking too much space.

Following is output screenshot:

[image]

Shall i use table to construct this in proper wrapped text?

Using Bootstart UI:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <form:form method="POST" modelattribute="partsForm" class="form-signin" action="/createpart">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">

                            <div class="col-sm-12">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                        <label for="partNo" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Part No</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <form:input type="text" path="partNo" class="form-control" placeholder="Part No" required="required"></form:input>
                                            <!--                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="partNo" placeholder="Part Number"> -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                        <label for="jobOpened" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">List of Jobs Opened</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <select multiple="" class="form-control" id="jobOpened">
                                                <option>111</option>
                                                <option>222</option>
                                                <option>333</option>
                                                <option>444</option>
                                                <option>555</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <label for="partStockQty" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Part in Stock Qty</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <form:input type="number" path="partInStockQty" class="form-control" placeholder="Part in Stock Qty" required="required"></form:input>
<!--                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="partStockQty" placeholder="Part in Stock Qty"> -->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <label for="partLocNew" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Part Location New</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <form:input type="number" path="partLocationNew" class="form-control" placeholder="Part Location New" required="required"></form:input>
<!--                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="partLocNew" placeholder="Part Location New"> -->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <!--                                                        <label for="partLocOld" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Part Location Old</label> -->
                                                <!--                                                        <div class="col-sm-9"> -->
                                                <!--                                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="partLocOld" placeholder="Part Location Old"> -->
                                                <!--                                                        </div> -->
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <label for="partLocOld" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Part Location Old</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <form:input type="number" path="partLocationOld" class="form-control" placeholder="Part Location Old" required="required"></form:input>
<!--                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="partLocOld" placeholder="Part Location Old"> -->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <label for="blankQty" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Blank QTY</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <form:input type="number" path="blankQty" class="form-control" placeholder="Blank QTY" required="required"></form:input>
<!--                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="blankQty" placeholder="Blank QTY"> -->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <label for="blankQtyLocation" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Blank QTY Location</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <form:input type="number" path="blankQtyLocation" class="form-control" placeholder="Blank QTY Location" required="required"></form:input>
<!--                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="blankQtyLocation" placeholder="Blank QTY Location"> -->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<!--                    <div class="row"> -->
<!--                        <table class="table table-bordered  table-hover"> -->
<!--                            <thead> -->
<!--                                <tr> -->
<!--                                    <th>PO Number</th> -->
<!--                                    <th>QTY</th> -->
<!--                                    <th>Shipped Date</th> -->
<!--                                    <th>Invoice No</th> -->
<!--                                    <th>Invoice Date</th> -->
<!--                                </tr> -->
<!--                            </thead> -->
<!--                            <tbody> -->
<!--                                <tr> -->
<!--                                    <td>12345-456</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>10</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>25-10-2020</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>32332</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>25-08-2020</td> -->
<!--                                </tr> -->
<!--                                <tr> -->
<!--                                    <td>12345-456</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>10</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>25-10-2020</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>32332</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>25-08-2020</td> -->
<!--                                </tr> -->
<!--                                <tr> -->
<!--                                    <td>12345-456</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>10</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>25-10-2020</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>32332</td> -->
<!--                                    <td>25-08-2020</td> -->
<!--                                </tr> -->
<!--                            </tbody> -->
<!--                        </table> -->
<!--                    </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>

        </form:form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#createCust').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                documentCommon.ajax({
                    dataType : 'text',
                    url : "/createcustomer",
                    data : $("body form:first").serialize(),
                    success : function(data) {
                        $(".dialogTitle").html("");
                        $(".dialogTitle").html("Create Customer");
                        $(".actualData").html("");
                        $(".actualData").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
    
            $('#updateCust').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                documentCommon.ajax({
                    dataType : 'text',
                    url : "/updatecustomer",
                    data : $("body form:first").serialize(),
                    success : function(data) {
                        $(".dialogTitle").html("");
                        $(".dialogTitle").html("Update/Delete Customer");
                        $(".actualData").html("");
                        $(".actualData").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
            $('#deleteCust').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                documentCommon.ajax({
                    dataType : 'text',
                    url : "/deletecustomer",
                    data : $("body form:first").serialize(),
                    success : function(data) {
                        $(".dialogTitle").html("");
                        $(".dialogTitle").html("Update/Delete Customer");
                        $(".actualData").html("");
                        $(".actualData").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
<!--        <script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<!--        <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<!--        <script src="js/custom.js"></script> -->
    </div>
```

Comment: This is how col is made. Here you set `label` and `input` into the same column so this is the normal way to be. How would you like to have that ? Label over input ? Label larger than input?

Comment: @MaxiGui
I want like Part No has much distance from Textbox. They should get closer but more important the text jumps to next line and i want it to be on same line. Not sure if font need to be small or how is it done in bootstrap.

Comment: Then the thing you can do is make the label larger because now, you just gave them `col-3` and input `col-9` so change this values to let more space for the label. But you might need to change the font-size.